# Get OSM building heights using height or building:levels tags

Tags: openstreetmap, ogr, ogr2ogr

I want to parse OSM data and to get all buildings with height or building:levels data.

I changed osmconf.ini file to read height and building:levels tags as separate columns for multipolygon layer but after all this i get an error `ERROR 1: "height" not recognised as an available field. ERROR 1: SetAttributeFilter(building is not null and (height is not null or building_levels is not null)) on layer 'multipolygons' failed.`

This is ogr2ogr command I used `ogr2ogr -f "GPKG" -where "building is not null and (height is not null or building_levels is not null)" building_height.gpkg us-latest.osm.pbf multipolygons -progress --config OSM_CONFIG_FILE "C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.10\\share\\gdal\\osmconf.ini"`

I have no idea why it is not working.

Here is osmconf.ini snippet for mulitpolygons:

```
[multipolygons]
# common attributes
# note: for multipolygons, osm_id=yes instantiates a osm_id field for the id of relations
# and a osm_way_id field for the id of closed ways. Both fields are exclusively set.
osm_id=yes
osm_version=no
osm_timestamp=no
osm_uid=no
osm_user=no
osm_changeset=no

# keys to report as OGR fields
attributes=name,type,aeroway,amenity,admin_level,barrier,boundary,building,craft,geological,historic,land_area,landuse,leisure,man_made,military,natural,office,place,shop,sport,tourism,industrial,addr:city,addr:state,addr:street,addr:postcode,addr:housenumber,addr:unit, height, building:levels
# keys that should NOT be reported in the "other_tags" field
ignore=area,created_by,converted_by,source,time,ele,note,openGeoDB:,fixme,FIXME
# uncomment to avoid creation of "other_tags" field
#other_tags=no
# uncomment to create "all_tags" field. "all_tags" and "other_tags" are exclusive
#all_tags=yes

[multilinestrings]
# common attributes
osm_id=yes
osm_version=no
osm_timestamp=no
osm_uid=no
osm_user=no
osm_changeset=no

# keys to report as OGR fields
attributes=name,type
# keys that should NOT be reported in the "other_tags" field
ignore=area,created_by,converted_by,source,time,ele,note,openGeoDB:,fixme,FIXME
# uncomment to avoid creation of "other_tags" field
#other_tags=no
# uncomment to create "all_tags" field. "all_tags" and "other_tags" are exclusive
#all_tags=yes
```

Comment: I would initially try without the spaces in the attributes= line.

Comment: That solved the problem, thanks.

Comment: I will add it as an answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the spaces from the line:

```
attributes=name,type,aeroway,amenity,admin_level,barrier,boundary,building,craft,geological,historic,land_area,landuse,leisure,man_made,military,natural,office,place,shop,sport,tourism,industrial,addr:city,addr:state,addr:street,addr:postcode,addr:housenumber,addr:unit, height, building:levels
```